# Execute cancel command after edit is pressed in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to automatically cancel the gridviews edit function by calling cancel immediatly:

```
protected virtual void GridView1_OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     //cancel gridviews edit
     //hide the visibility one one panel and show the visibility of another populated panel
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Use link button and On clicking on that, Redirect it to other page as you have edit page.

Comment: If you are doing a redirect why do you need to cancel out of interest?

Comment: Sorry, I am not doing a redirect. I am hiding the visibility one one panel and showing the visibility of another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Cancel` property of the `GridViewEditEventArgs e` to `true` as described on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventargs.aspx).